# How to load *part* of a multifeature geojson file in R?

Tags: r, loading, geojson, ropensci

I have a geojson that is a `FeatureCollection` containing 2 geographic data types: a `LineString` and a `waypoint` - see the raw file [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Robinlovelace/stplanr/master/inst/extdata/route_data.geojson) - this is how it looks on [GitHub](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/stplanr/blob/master/inst/extdata/route_data.geojson):

[image: the-data]

I want to load only only the `LineString`, so this is what I do:

```
library(RCurl)
obj <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Robinlovelace/stplanr/master/inst/extdata/route_data.geojson")
writeLines(obj, "/tmp/obj.geojson")
obj <- readLines("/tmp/obj.geojson")
just_lines <- obj[14:(length(obj) - 28)]
just_lines[1] <- paste0("{",  just_lines[1])
just_lines[length(just_lines)] <- "}"
writeLines(just_lines, "/tmp/just_lines.geojson")
```

Now we have removed the pesky lines at the beginning and end of the file, it's a nicely formed GeoJSON file that we can load and plot, yay:

```
library(rgdal)
route <- readOGR("/tmp/just_lines.geojson", layer = "OGRGeoJSON")
plot(route)
```

[image: line in R]

Except it should be obvious to any R user that this is a very clunky and inefficient way of doing this involving too many lines of code and unnecessary reading and writing to the hard disc. There must be another way!

### Options I've looked at

- [geojsonio](https://github.com/ropensci/geojsonio)
- [jsonlite](https://github.com/jeroenooms/jsonlite)
- [leaflet](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet), which can display the `FeatureCollection` but seemingly not extract its parts.

### Context

I'm creating a package for sustainable transport planning, [stplanr](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/stplanr). A [function](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/stplanr/blob/master/R/gFlow.R) to find cycling routes (like in the image below) needs to load in the [FeatureCollection geojson data](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/stplanr/raw/master/inst/extdata/route_data.geojson) from the [CycleStreets.net api](http://www.cyclestreets.net/api/).

[image: flow]

Comment: Do you want an R spatial object like `route` or do you require it saved to a geoJSON file?

Comment: Best as a Spatial object.

Comment: with or without the attributes?

Comment: Would be very useful to have those attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the data using jsonlite direct from the URL:

```
 obj <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Robinlovelace/stplanr/master/inst/extdata/route_data.geojson")
```

Convert the first object in the collection to SpatialLines:

```
 sl = SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(obj$features[1,]$geometry$coordinates[[1]])),ID=1)))
 plot(sl)
```

That assumes the feature is a single line string.

To make a SpatialLinesDataFrame with the attributes:

```
 sldf=SpatialLinesDataFrame(sl=sl,data=obj$features[1,]$properties)
```

Should probably also give it a CRS:

```
 proj4string(sldf)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
```

Comment: Much more concise. Much faster too! already in my evolving package: https://github.com/Robinlovelace/stplanr/commit/9958c8810a1944bc353276320c1675245c5a9c46

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible in LeafletR but Leaflet's `L.GeoJSON` layer has a `filter` method which can render (or not render) a collection's features based on the properties the feature has. Some code:

```
L.geoJson(geojson, {
  'filter': function (feature) {
    return feature.geometry.type === 'LineString'
  }
});
```

An example: http://plnkr.co/edit/RXIO0X?p=preview

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-filter